# view google map on PC via bluestacks

Tags: android, google-maps, bluestacks

I'm trying to develop an android application and I need to use GOOGLE MAPS in it. However I dont have an mobile to test it, so I'm using bluestacks. But I always get a grey screen with GOOGLE logo in the bottom left.

So how can I fix it, any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is occurring because you did not get an `API_KEY` in the Developer's Console. To resolve this, you need to follow the documentation [Get a Google Maps Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_4_get_a_google_maps_api_key). You need API keys in order to access Google APIs.